# Entity Framework: Store entity property in json format

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

Let's say you've an entity that has a property typed as `ICollection<string>` and I want to store it as `varchar` in SQL Server in JSON format.

How to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably You should have another string property in your Model class to hold the JSON represntation of the Collection of string. and that property will be mapped to your Table. Do not map the Collection property to your Table. Something like this

```
public class Customer
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string JsonData { set;get;}
  [NotMapped]
  public ICollection<string> Items { set;get;}
}
```

And Before saivng the data to your table, You need to fill the `JsonData` property value by reading the `Items` Propert value.

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser= new JavaScriptSerializer();    
string JsonData= ser.Serialize(Items);
```

Bytheway, Are you sure you want to store the `JSON` representation in the table ? Why not use Master - details approach. store the JSON data into normalized tables. Whenever you want to build the JSON back, you can do it in C#.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a workaround, but I was wondering if there's some *oficial approach*. Something like an interceptor when adding or updating, so you can transform and customize some entity property persistence.

Comment: About your "update". It's another workaround. In NHibernate I'm able of implementing a custom type so you can use regular properties and define how to store them in the database. I was looking for something like this.