# Entity Framework 5 do not save array string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have a simple array inside a model using the entity framework 5. The array will not saved inside the table.

**Model**

```
public class MyModel: IEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<string> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

**Config**

```
    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

**Initializer**

```
internal class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        context.MyModels.Add(new MyModel {
           MyArray = new [] { "Value1", "Value2" }
        });
   }
}
```

Any hint why this does' not work. MyArray not event appear as a column.

Comment: do you know a database where you have a column type which is an array ? I don't, Entity Framework probably doesn't either, so it's not created as a column. In a normalized model, you should have another entity / table to save your "Values" and a one to many relationship with MyModel.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes, its possible, NHibernate. You can also do fancy stuff with it like blobbing JSON. http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/03/ormlite-blobbing-done-with-nhibernate-and-serialized-json/

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus had expected that it got serialized, nothing special... and it's to late to use a different o/r mapper.

Comment: @Phill column type in db is not an array in your example, and we're talking about entity framework. So ? By the way, even if possible, it's a very bad way (normalization, even when using an ORM, is a rather good thing - I think).

Comment: @Abc then don't declare it as an array in your model, just as a string, and make serialization yourself ?

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus Yes but the json output should be an array (using mvc4), is there a way to autogenerate table with a attribute or something like this.

Comment: I guess you're right @RaphaëlAlthaus, its not an array. So... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html use a database that supports arrays. Normalization is good where it makes sense. Over normalization is pointless, creates too many joins, and leads to performance issues. But we digress. Yes its possible to do what the OP wants, but hes stuck with the technologies hes chosen.

Comment: Well, if you absolutely don't wanna normalize,  just save your data as a serialized json string . When you retrieve it, deserialize it ? Maybe see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759341/entity-framework-store-entity-property-in-json-format

Comment: Well, not too hard to dig : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx , but.. that's your choice :

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array of strings, you can alternatively use a simple string column with some kind of separator like ';' or '|', anything will do. Just make sure that when you retrieve your data from the database you call the C# String.Split method, passing to it the same separator as parameter.

For example:

```
string stringToBePersisted = "First Value|Second Value|Third Value";

string[] stringsRetrieved = columnValue.Split('|');
```